# What is difference between ANY and IN clause in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Neo4j has two different clauses to find value in an array, ANY and IN. Please explain, how they are different as both are used to filter the data by checking if, the specified value is present in the array or not.
[image]

Query#1 : MATCH (n) WHERE any(color IN n.liked_colors WHERE color = 'yellow') RETURN n

Result#1: Node with name Eskil

Query#2 : Match (n) where 'yellow' in n.liked_colors return n

Result#2: Node with name Eskil

If both query return same results then where is the diffrence.

Comment: They are semantically equivalent in this particular example. One thing to consider is whether they perform the same or not. For that, prefix both queries with `PROFILE` and see what happens: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/query-options/#how-do-i-profile-a-query

Answer (score 0):

In your simple example case the results are the same.

However `any()` allows more complex means of filtering, especially when we aren't using this to simply detect membership of a known value in a list:

```
MATCH (n:Person) 
WHERE any(color in n.liked_colors WHERE (n)<-[:KNOWS|MARRIED*]-(other:Person {eyes:color}))
```

Find a person where for any of their liked colors, we can traverse the given pattern to find another person with eyes of that color.